# How to pass two variables through a link

Tags: php, html, variables, href

I'm trying to pass two variables through a link. Here's my code that failed.

```
<a href="appGpa.php?id=<?php echo $row->user_id;?>&amp;year=$year">
```

I currently have no problems passing the id. The only problem is the year. It prompts an error that says year is undefined. The year variable is passed perfectly from another page and I've retrieved it using `$year = (int)$_GET['year'];`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: you forgot this <?php echo $year;?>

Comment: @Miggy Aha that did the trick! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that "$year" is also wrapped inside "php" tag

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
<a href="appGpa.php?id=<?php echo $row->user_id.'&year='.$year; ?>"/>
```

OR

```
<a href="appGpa.php?id=<?php echo $row->user_id;?>&year=<?php echo $year; ?>"/>
```

OR

```
<a href="appGpa.php?id=<?= $row->user_id;?>&year=<?= $year; ?>"/>
```

OR

```
<a href="appGpa.php?id=<?php echo "{$row->user_id}&year={$year}"; ?>"/>
```